# How do I edit the "colHeader" value dynamically? (autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I would like to be able to edit the text (value) of colHeaders in a Handsontable (v0.17.0) dynamically (for example with ) and add "jquery autocomplete" there.

The problem, if i use normal cells as "headers" and style it with css is, that i can´t move the cells... Is there any other solution to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by updating the `colHeaders` using `.updateSettings()`. All you'd need to do is create your new column headers array and update the settings.

```
hotInstance.updateSettings({
    colHeaders: newColHeaders // where newColHeaders is the updated array
})
```

That should do it.